# Realistic Gingerbread Material

Tags: shaders

Christmas is coming quickly, and I'm working out a way of quickly designing gingerbread houses.

So far, everything is working except the gingerbread shader.

At the moment, I want it to look as real as possible, to something like this:

[image]

This is the closest I can get:

[image]

If someone would be able to either give advice, a node setup, or just help me to understand it better, I would appreciate it greatly.

Ultimate outcome would be to have a shader that looked like the picture.

[.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52637) .blend doesn't include the HDRi, so light it as you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did

[image: GingerbreadHouse]

[image: NodeSetup]

For the displacement, I mixed different Noise Textures with different settings to them with a bunch of Mix RGB nodes. At the end, I mixed the Noise textures with a Musgrave texture too add some lumpiness to the displacement.

You can play around with the noise settings to achieve the look you want.

For the color, I attached the noise textures to a color ramp, black being a darker brown, and white being a lighter brown, and plugged that into the base color of the principled BSDF shader.

I didn't change any of the BSDF shader settings, but I realized it might help if you increased the roughness.

I hope I helped out.

Comment: Amazing! Thankyou very much! This is exactly what I wanted.